# Yii - How to Hide Button in CGridView for Specific Record?

Tags: php, yii

I'm working in a project. How to hide just only a button for specific record in cgridview?
[image]

Hope anyone can give me suggestion for this problem. Thanks all.

Comment: I think you shouldn't rely on hidden a button as a way for a user to not delete a certain record. Care to clarify a little bit more about the purpose? It may help to find alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `"visible"` attribute for this button in your `CButtonColumn` and pass a **PHP expression** (within single quotes) to control when it gets shown and when it doesn't:

For example, the following example would make the object having attribute `"name"` equal to `"Kasi"` **not be shown**. You can adapt it to your needs.

```
[
    'class' =>'CButtonColumn',
    'template'=>'{view}{update}{delete}'
    'buttons'=>[
        'delete'=>[
            'visible'=>'($data->name !== "Kasi")'
        ]
    ]
]
```

Not much info, but here's the link to the official docs: [docs for attribute 'visible'](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridColumn#visible-detail)

Answer (score 0):

**in columns array add this**

```
array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{view}{update}',
        'buttons'=>array(
            'view' => array(
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("controller/action", array("id"=>$data[id]))',
            ),
            'update' => array(
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("controller/action", array("id"=>$data[id]))',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```